# how to install Tensorrt in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorrt

I installed Tensorrt zip file, i am trying to install tensorrt but it is showing some missing dll file error.i am new in that how to use tensorrt and CUDA engine. How to use C++ API to convert into CUDA engine also. As reference i am attaching screenshot also.

Someone can help me Please.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UN1y.png)

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow your question looks a little bit hard to answer, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't add /lib to your PATH.

You should either add the /TensorRT-x.x.x.x/lib/ to PATH or move all the files in the folder to your CUDA folder (/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v.x.x/bin/).

More on the installation guide:
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html